# File Upload jQuery in background

Tags: web-apps, javascript, jquery

#### My situation:

- I am writing an application that allows users to upload very large files. (In some cases over a very slow network)
- I would like to let users start the upload of a file, and then browse to other parts of the application/site.

#### What I've tried:

I have tried creating a hidden `iframe` on the same page in order to create a separate DOM that will be preserved upon redirect.  I was initially going to have the visible file input fire an onsubmit that would send the file over to the iframe's DOM, then have it run an upload using [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).

However, for [security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021526/programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-type-file-input-html-element?answertab=votes#tab-top), javascript does not allow programmatic setting of a fileupload input.  So this approach failed.

#### What I'm looking for:

I'm looking for some sort of javascript/jQuery plugin or library that will allow me to keep fileuploads running in the background of my application. (Or better yet if you could point me to a way to do it with [this plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)).

#### Criteria:

- File uploads should be:

  - Chunked
  - Resumable
  - Able to run in the background
  - Should be compatible with Ruby on Rails 4  (in case that's an issue)

Comment: How about popup the upload page in a separate browser window? Unless your whole app is ajax-driven and you can keep the uploading block of code still, then I'm not sure. Hope someone could help :)

Comment: Haven't tested, but I suspect it is possible to make the upload work while allowing the user to navigate if we capture the request in a service worker. Yes, this question is prior service workers, I notice. There won't be plugins for that, unless they are for a javascript framework that includes a service worker, and no, jQuery does not. So this would have to become a question for StackOverflow (I mean, how to write a service worker for that, not what framework has it... what framework has it would be a question for this side, I wonder if there is any).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`ajaxForm`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) easily:

```
<form id="uploadform">
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
```

Then in your javascript just do this:

```
$("#uploadform").ajaxForm();
```

If you want to do something when then upload is done, you can just give it a callback(for example in this navigate to another location):

```
$("#uploadform").ajaxForm(function () {
    window.location = "/some-other-part";
});
```

Comment: How about what he said "and then browse to other parts of the application/site." ?

Comment: `$("#uploadform").ajaxForm(function () { window.location = "/some-other-part"; });`

Comment: You mean he could keep the upload running and navigate to other pages from the same window?

Comment: No, I'm the code above it will navigate when the upload is finished

Comment: Yup, that what I was talking about. I'm not 100% sure what the OP meant, but I think he wanted the user to be able to navigate to other pages while the upload is still going, which IMO I dont think it's possible unless he do the upload in a separate popup window or have the website being AJAX driven which will keep the uploading code still available even if he requested other pages. Anyhow, thanks for your replies :) I was also curious to see if that is possible.

Comment: So if my answer is useful, can I get an upvote? :P

Comment: Well, it depends on the person who asked the question. But I don't think it helped him since he got only two requirements, if you read the second one: *"I would like to let users start the upload of a file, and then browse to other parts of the application/site."* **He meant to Browse during the upload, not after.**